# How do I disable a VM Locks using Azure REST APIs?

Tags: python, azure, api, rest, locks

I'm working on an API that uses Azure REST APIs to delete a VM, with disks and network interfaces when given a specific VM name in the URL. I was told the first thing I have to do is fetch the locks associated with the VM and disable them.

I found that I can obtin the locks by calling the Azure API "list of locks at Subscription_ID level":

> `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks?api-version=2016-09-01`

This returns a json payload with a list of locks with the respective VMs that are associated:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "level": "CanNotDelete",
                "notes": "This storage is used for quarterly image create automation in XX X X"
            },
            "id": "/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{VMname}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks/{LockName}",
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks",
            "name": "XX_XX_XXXX"
        }
```

In this payload I can see both lock and VM, but I haven't found an API for disabling the lock, or removing it.
What would be the best way to remove this VM lock through Python REST API?

Answer (score 0):

To delete a lock, you can use [`Management Locks - Delete By Scope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/management-locks/delete-by-scope?tabs=HTTP) REST API operation. For `scope` parameter, you can simply pass the `id` obtained from the list operation.